# Finding the difference of 2 image's pixel values and then creating a new images based on the difference

Tags: python, numpy, raspberry-pi, python-imaging-library, rgb

I want to create a program that takes a picture of the same area at 2 different times and then compares the images, and then creates an entirely new image that has just the difference between the 2 images (what changed). I am using RGB values and I am looking to see if they are more than 90% different in value then I want to add those pixels to the new matrix, which will be mapped.
I am fairly new to Raspberry Pi and python so I ran into an error and I don't understand why it is giving me that error.

I have tried using both PIL and Numpy but both methods produce errors that I can't fix

THIS ISN'T THE ENTIRE CODE, BUT THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT IS GIVING ME THE ERROR:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import picamera
import time
import RPi.GPIO 
from guizero import ...

def processimage():
    before = Image.open('before.jpg')
    after = Image.open('after.jpg')

    beforeRGB = np.array(before)
    afterRGB = np.array(after)

    outputRGB = Image.new('RGB', (800,480))

    x=0
    y=0
    for x in range(800):
        for y in range(480):
            if(((beforeRGB[x,y,0])/afterRGB[x,y,0])<0.9):
                outputRGB[x,y,0] = afterRGB[x,y,0]
            else:
                output[x,y,0] = 255

            if(((beforeRGB[x,y,1])/afterRGB[x,y,1])<0.9):
                outputRGB[x,y,1] = afterRGB[x,y,1]
            else:
                output[x,y,1] = 255

            if(((beforeRGB[x,y,2])/afterRGB[x,y,2])<0.9):
                outputRGB[x,y,2] = afterRGB[x,y,2]
            else:
                output[x,y,2] = 255


            y=y+1
         x=x+1

    Image.fromarray(outputRGB).save('output.jpg')
```

THIS IS THE ERROR I AM GETTING

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1562, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/guizero/PushButton.py", 
line 146, in _command_callback
    self._command()
  File "/home/pi/ButtonTest/GUI_interface.py", line 70, in mode
    lifetime(key)
  File "/home/pi/ButtonTest/GUI_interface.py", line 158, in lifetime
    processimage()
  File "/home/pi/ButtonTest/GUI_interface.py", line 115, in processimage
    outputRGB[x,y,0] = afterRGB(x,y,0)
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Comment: This approach will take forever, especially on a Raspberry Pi. You need to vectorise your code by using Numpy instead of `for` loops. Try doing `diff = np.float(beforeRGB)/np.float(afterRGB)` instead and looking at `diff`. Then look at `np.where()` to choose either the original image or `255`. Also consider that the difference maybe be between 0.9 and 1.1 depending whether the image got brighter or darker...

Answer (score 0):

1) The error message doesn't match the code. The error message is about a different version of the code where `()` where used accidentally instead of `[]`, see last code line of the error message.

2) Iterating over individual pixels is very slow when using Python. Please read through a couple of image processing tutorials to get an understanding of vectorization and broadcasting.

For example, the code above could be shortened to something like:

```
output = np.where(beforeRGB/afterRGB < 0.9, afterRGB, 255]
```

3) `for x in range()` already iterates over all x values in the range. There is no need to increment x or y at the end of the loop.

4) The formula chosen for the image difference produces division by zero for pixels where at least one of the channels is 0. Do some research and choose a better metric for image differences.